# Creating a stripe token with Ruby on Rails backend & Reactjs frontend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Trying to create stripe token

this is my frontend fetch

```
  const response = fetch('api/v1/charges', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(paymentData),
  });
```

then stripe gives this example code for creating a token on the server side. Where is an ideal place to put this? Controller, model, initializer?

```
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_3Sq3Q'

token = params[:stripeToken]

charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  amount: 999,
  currency: 'usd',
  description: 'Example charge',
  source: token,
})
```

Clearly I'm new to this but some advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I would add the API key `Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_3Sq3Q'` in an initializer of considering how the application code is structured also combining it with a configuration file

The second part is receiving the request parameters and creating a new object of `Stripe::Charge`. This would be in controller.

Another way could be to encapsulate the logic related with Stripe in a small Stripe client class. This class can have methods that deal with the connection with Stripe API.

Example:

```
class StripeClient

  def create_charge(options)
    # Here can be handled different exceptions as
    # what to return in case of a failure?
    Stripe::Charge.create({
      amount: options[:amount],
      currency: options[currency],
      description: options[:description],
      source: options[:token],
   })
  end 
end
```

From controller then use the `StripeClient`

```
token = params[:stripeToken]
options = {
  amount: 999,
  currency: 'usd',
  description: 'Example charge',
  source: token
}
StripeClient.new.create_charge(options)
```

From my experience I find it more clean to have third-party API calls in specific classes or modules.

Hope this helps you!